# Codeigniter 2x firefox session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem with the sessions in firefox browsers, everything works in Chrome and IE - it saves sessions correctly , but Firefox doesn't . I've tried with Native sessions to save in the db the session - in FF it saves it but again not working, just after login to the page it redirects as if I'm not logged in.It does this things only in FF. I saw other questions like this and from them I saw the Native session classs, but no use.

Comment: I use CI app in FF and it works just as well as in other browsers

Comment: Did you try disabling `$config['sess_match_user_agent'];` just as a debugging measure?

Answer (score 2):

For this same problem I use the following header in Controller constructor and it did the trick.

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on codeigniter, what happened is that my user agent had to many characters for the custom DB field that CI documentation tells you to create.

try making and alter table to change the user_agent field on ci_sessions and check again if firefox works.

```
ALTER TABLE `ci_sessions` MODIFY COLUMN `user_agent` VARCHAR(160) not null
```

Answer (score 0):

if CI session class is not working with only Firefox then it's a cookies issue. 
enable cookies for your domain name under Fifrefox as following

> tools->options->privacy->history: use custom settings for history;
>   check "accept cookies" and add your domain to your exceptions, allow your domain www.your_domain.com  and that's it;

more details in this link for different FF versions:

http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Cookies-in-Firefox