# php codeigniter session doees not show correctly in Firefox

Tags: php, codeigniter, firefox, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a question related to cookie and session. Login page works very well in google chrome but unfortunately when I run program in Firefox it doesn't show properly. It means that I cant see my character that I typed in login and password in Firefox. config of session and cookie is as following.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']   = '';
$config['cookie_path']    = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']   = true;
$config['cookie_httponly']     = FALSE;
```

Comment: I think its a duplicate question you can check the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861983/codeigniter-2x-firefox-session. Also you can check here https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/1102

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problem like this before, My session destroyed every time when I open firebug, So the setting to solve this problem is simply:

Change this line:

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
```

to this in your config.php file:

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with change session.save_path in your php.ini file.

or you can change it like:-

```
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
```

it will save sessions in directory and it will prevent the issue with session